# My external HardDisks aren't being spun down - Linux Mint 14

Tags: hard-drive, linux-mint

I have recently noticed that my external harddisks are not getting spun down when they are idle. This may not be too bad, if it were not for the fact that the older one seems to have a ventilation problem. It has hit a max of 64 C(!!!) so far.

I have tried to enable it on the Gnome Disks Utility. It shows "Enter Standby After 1 minute" right now, however it does not. The same utility allows me to manually force a spin down. One of my HDDs works with this while the other shows the below error message. Both fail for auto standby.

[image]

Can someone suggest anything to rectify this? For now I am just disconnecting the drive that overheats. Both drives had samba shares, I disabled them, didnt seem to help. I am not sure if this will help, but I noticed it first after I did a big update of my Mint setup abt a few months ago.

p.s. Sometimes it looks like the drive spins down, only to get spun up again.

Comment: Usually this happens when a program is accessing a file on the drive without you noticing it, I ran into a somewhat similar problem before, but that was on windows and I don't know of many linux programs that could do something like that without notice.

Comment: @user88311 I thought of that. But the one that is overheating has nothing that I know that should do that.. No torrents, no dropbox, etc. And disabling shares didnt help. How did you figure out the application? I could probably run a windows app via wine if you know one?

Comment: Honestly, I'd use task manager to look for any processes that shouldn't be running, as a common issue with some windows programs is after you close them the process will keep running, not to prone to linux, but I'm sure there is a similar function within it.

Comment: @user88311 problem is the disk is used mainly as a storage only, and so there is no program that should be accessing it.. thanks though